# Logger.setLevel() doesn't enable logging correctly

Tags: java, log4j

Situation: I have this log4j logger:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ThisClassName.class);
```

And am trying to set it programatically through:

```
Logger.getLogger(ThisClassName.class).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

Still, DEBUG level prints are swalloed (while INFO prints are printed successfully).

Even this bit has no effect: `Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);`

Calling logger.debug("foo") reaches `Category.forcedLog()` and `ConsoleAppender.doAppend()`, and then fails (quits) at:

```
if(!isAsSevereAsThreshold(event.getLevel()))
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a configuration file somewhere whose value could be conflicting with your programmatic settings?

Comment: @justky - I looked through all 8 log4j.properties files scattered around our project, and none of them has a level on any appender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your appender is configured with a threshold greater than debug, so while the logger doesn't ignore the entries, your appender doesn't record it.  You need to configure the threshold of your `ConsoleAppender` to be `DEBUG` as well, either through your config file or programatically:

```
((ConsoleAppender)someLogger.getAppender("CONSOLE")).setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
```

Config files are usually the more elegant solution for this sort of thing.

**Edit**:  Note that apparently, any subclass of `AppenderSkeleton` (including `ConsoleAppender`) [shouldn't have a threshold filter set by default](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html#threshold).  So it's likely that somewhere in your configuration you're actually manually assigning a threshold ( > Debug) to that appender, as @justkt hints.

Comment: The config file may be one that comes with an application server (JBoss, for example, defaults to INFO) and not one that the OP set up him/herself.  It's wise to look around for him/her to verify.

Comment: I'm running this as a standlone java class (from IntelliJ actually). See my comment on the question - I haven't found a bad appender config in log4j.properties files. Setting the threshold did work (I did it on the root logger)